# How to do parametrized testing with NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, webdriver

Does anyone know how to do parametrized testing with NUnit and C#?

Especially I want to drive a parametrized tests with Selenium WebDriver

With the selenium RC I was able to do with this with iteration and selenium.Stop(); / selenium.Start();

Is there any better approach?

Comment: To be able to do again the same test steps with different test data

Comment: tried to improve your question & deleted older comments

Comment: Improve your question. What are you trying to achieve? You mention different test data, in which case: if you are trying to repeat a test case just with different test data, look at NUnit's parametrised test case attributes. Nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: Hi,You are right. I need to use parametrised NUnit test. Can you please give me an example that how can I give a parameter from NUnit test for my test method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit supports several approaches for parameterized unit testing, in particular:

- [[Values]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=values&r=2.6) attribute, typically in combination with [[Combinatorial]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=combinatorial&r=2.6) (default) or [[Sequential]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=sequential&r=2.6)
- [[TestCase]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6) attribute
- [[TestCaseSource]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6) attribute

Instead of `[Values]` you could also consider [[Random]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=random&r=2.6) or [[Range]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=range&r=2.6).

If you want to restart your Selenium Webdriver for every parameterization, I expect it would suffice to initialize the webdriver in a `[Setup]` method and close it in a `[TearDown]` method in your `[TestFixture]` class, for example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WebTests
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void StartDriver()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void StopDriver()
    {
        driver.Quit();
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

I have not used Selenium WebDriver myself, so the following links have been of help to me in writing this response:

- [Automatically start and stop SeleniumRC with NUnit](http://silent-code.blogspot.se/2009/09/automatically-start-and-stop-seleniumrc.html)
- [Introducing the Selenium-WebDriver API by Example](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example)